# UI-grid applying calculation to column

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Right now when I change the %Discount field value, 
the "Product Column Dynamic Total" changes.
I also want the "x (default)" column cell values to change as well in respect of the % change.

https://plnkr.co/edit/B40h9XrKOcNly7M0HG0u?p=preview

```
  Product Column Dynamic Total >> {{grandTotal -  (discount / 100) * grandTotal}} <<
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to change and update `$scope.myData` when `discount` changes. Since, `ui-grid` has two way binding for `$scope.myData` it will update the view.
You `input` tag will look like:

```
<input class="form-control "  data-ng-model="discount" ng-change="updateValues()" type="number">
```

then add the `updateValues` function to your `$scope`:

```
$scope.updateValues = function() {
   // write code to update values here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forked your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HWV8x1jKCi9VRgGprYnX?p=preview) to change value of "x (default)" column with some random values.

Code:

`angular.forEach($scope.myData,function(row,idx){
row.x = Math.random();
});`

It is not advised to used watchers to implement a functionality. Instead use functions.